# iOS and Android generating different hash values in SHA512

Tags: ios, swift, hash, apple-cryptokit

We need to verify hash value coming from the server. Android part is working. On iOS side we use CryptoKit to generate hash value.
Passing as paramater "jsonString" from which the hash key needs to be generated and "hasValue" which needs to be matched. While both functions use the same algorythm the outcome is always different.

> let digest = SHA512.hash(data: jsonStringWithSaltBytes)

> let hasBytes = digest.bytes

In computeHas function when we try to get the `let hasBytes = digest.bytes` it always give different HashBytes after SHA512.hash bytes conversion.

```
import CryptoKit

extension Digest {
    var bytes: [UInt8] { Array(makeIterator()) }
    var data: Data { Data(bytes) }
}

func generateHasKey(jsonString: String, hasValue: String) -> Bool {
    let data = Data(base64Encoded: hasValue)
    let hashWithSaltByte: [UInt8] = Array(data!)
    let hashSizeByts: Int = 512 / 8
    if hashWithSaltByte.count < hashSizeByts {
        return false
    }
    var saltBytesArr: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: (hasWithSaltByte.count - hashSizeInByts))
    for index in 0..<saltBytes.count {
        saltBytesArr[index] = hasWithSaltByte[hashSizeInByts + index]
    }
    let expectedHasString = computeHas(jsonString: jsonString, saltBytes: saltBytesArr)
    if expectedHashString == hasValue {
        print("Hash value match..")
        return true
    }else {
        print("Hash value did not match..")
        return false
    }

}

func computeHash(jsonString: String, saltBytes: [UInt8]) -> String {
    let saltBytes = saltBytes
    let jsonStringBytes: [UInt8] = Array(jsonString.utf8)
    var jsonStringWithSaltBytes: [UInt8] =  Array(repeating: 0, count: (jsonStringBytes.count + saltBytes.count))
    for index in 0..<jsonStringBytes.count {
        jsonStringWithSaltBytes[index] = jsonStringBytes[index]
    }
    for index in 0..<saltBytes.count {
        jsonStringWithSaltBytes[jsonStringBytes.count + index] = saltBytes[index]
    }
    let digest = SHA512.hash(data: jsonStringWithSaltBytes)
    let hashBytes = digest.bytes
    var hashWithSaltBytes: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: (hashBytes.count + saltBytes.count))
    
    for index in 0..<hasBytes.count {
        hashWithSaltBytes[index] = hashBytes[index]
    }
    for index in 0..<saltBytes.count {
        hashWithSaltBytes[hashBytes.count + index] = saltBytes[index]
    }
  
    let FinalsaltData = Data(hasWithSaltBytes)
    let finalHashString = FinalsaltData.base64EncodedString()
    
    return finalHashString ?? ""
}
```

Comment: Instead of this complicated array copy process you should create an empty SHA512 instance via `init()`, then feed the data via `update(data: Data(jsonString.utf8)` and `update(data: Date(saltBytes))` and the call `finalize()` to get the digest.